# open every .example file with /example/example.py in windows

Tags: python, windows

I want to make a programming language with a specific end of the files (.example) which can be in every folder and executed by the python file (example/example.py) with the argument where the .example file is, that the python file can open it.

I've already tried it to setup in the normal Windows Settings and on the .example itselfs (open with), but there is no chance for making it work.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

- arbitrary custom file extensions can be run with Windows python using the **file association feature** of windows

### Step by step (Windows 7)

- create you new file extension
- open the file as usual
- you will see `unable to find software to open this file`
- choose ... `search through windows`
- choose ... `Select a program from a list of installed programs`
- choose ... `Always use the selected program to open this kind of file`
- navigate to the directory containing pythonw.exe

### Screenshot

- [image: screenshot of windows file association step]

Comment: it is a python, not an .exe file! Windows says this app can't be executed on your pc when i'm chosing my python file there

Comment: That's what these steps are enumerating. You have a python source code file with a non-customary file extension, and you want to run it just as if it were python code. That's what the solution is explaining how to do.

Comment: and on windows 10